# JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Tags: joomla

I create one template for joomla 2.5. But when I installed it it show the error:

> "Failed loading XML file
>   D:\wamp\www\demoproject\tmp\install_51a44308e27b9\templateDetails.xml
>   XML: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
>   JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file"

How can I solve it please?

Answer (score 1):

It means your XML file isn't properly written. The actual error is:

```
XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

Check the file and make sure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

is the first line in the file. No line breaks or anything else is allowed before this.

Answer (score 0):

1. That means you try to install the wrong .zip file. It happens often if you try to install a Joomla 1.5 template to a Joomla 1.6 website or the other way around.
2. Another common reason is, that you try to install the templates download package (<- the ZIP Archive with all the template stuff inside, like the psd file, the docs AND the installation files) , instead of the included installation file.
3. `<extension version="2.5" type="template" client="site">` Try extension tag instead install.
4. `<!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 1.6//DTD template 1.0//EN" "http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/1.6/template-install.dtd">` Include the correct doc type.